# Image averaging every 10 frames

Tags: c++, opencv

Just a quick question. Is there a way for me to separate the frames from the webcam live stream into groups of 10 for image averaging? For example, take average for the first ten frames (1-10), then repeat the same for the next ten (11-20) and so on. I can do image averaging using cv::accumulate so I only need to know the command to group the frames

Answer (score 1):

Try moving average, it does not requres much additional memory.

Avg_img_next=(input_img+N*Avg_img_prev)/(N+1)

It will average N frames.

Images must have CV_32FC or CV_64FC type of elements, if you will implenment it from scratch.

You can also use addWeighted method to implement this. (alpha=1.0/(N+1), beta=N/(N+1), gamma=0).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your kind response. Can I trouble you with a question? Will the code will take the previous average into the new average calculation? Because currently, I just want independent, mutually-exclusive sets of averaged images. For example, if I have 20 pictures, I want to get 2 averaged images from 2 groups of 10 (group 1 is image 1 to 10 while group 2 is image 11 to 20). Again, I really appreciate your answer

Comment: The moving average is useful for online averaging, if you have to reduce noise on image stream of static scene for instance. In your case it may be better to use separate accumulators for groups of images to sum images up and then divide by their number of images in group, or use several moving average instances.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was hoping that there would be an automatic way to loop the function. In that case, can we change the approach to: "take average of all the captured frames every 2 seconds then continue to loop that for other independent set of frames "?

Comment: You can clear accumulator every N frames, then collect N frames and get the result.

Comment: I see. So my general idea will be

cv::Mat avgImg;
avgImg.create(width, height,CV_32FC3);

for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
  image = imread(fileName.c_str(),0);
  cv::accumulate(image, avgImg);
}

avgImg = avgImg / N;

avgImg.clear()

Will this do the job?

Comment: Something like that, but you also neet to set avgImage to zero before loop. And you load 1 channel, but created accumulator for 3 channel image.

Comment: One last question just to clear my misconception. Won't avgImg.clear()  set the image to zero? In term of channel, another part of the code I wrote will convert the captured frames to 3 channel iamges which will then be input in for imread() so I guess that will be okay.